# Python tabulate, appending element to current table

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm currently working on a continuous monitoring feature within a CLI. To have data printed neatly I decided to use [tabulate](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate) as it's exceptionally easy and works for pretty much everything I've thrown at it.

The issue is that the continuous monitoring feature polls based on a user-specified interval, however each time it polls, a new table is generated and printed.

Take the following snippet:

```
table_headers = ['Date', 'Message', 'Type']
mapped_data = []
...
...
...
print tabulate(mapped_data, headers=table_headers)
```

That would be an example of a single iteration, the `...` is where data is processed and appended. However the output would be like so:

```
Date                       Message           Type
-------------------------  --------------  ------
Thu 12 Nov 2015, 18:55:26  Message.             1
Thu 12 Nov 2015, 18:55:58  Message.             2
Date    Message    Type
------  ---------  ------
Date    Message    Type
------  ---------  ------
Date    Message    Type
------  ---------  ------
```

Ideally, I would like to construct a generic table and build it over time. Do note that the message must be printed as soon as it is received. Thus I cannot simply wait until the process is complete and print everything in one go.

---

Using `Python 2.7`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec) to do what you want.

<sup>**NOTE:** You need to know width of every column when you write your header.</sup>

Create a template of your rows:

```
template = '{:<25} {:<14} {:<6}' # numbers are width, '<' means 'align to left'
```

You can then create your header by writing:

```
print template.format(*table_headers)
```

Add dashes after it by writing:

```
# changes fill character to dash, and fills template with empty strings
print template.replace(':', ':-').format('', '', '')
```

And add rows by writing:

```
for row in mapped_data:
    print template.format(*row)
```

Comment: Cool approach, I would need to get a good idea of what the max width may be per column, if so the number of dashes could be equal to the max width for that column.