# Creating pretty python tables that get built up over time?

Tags: python, html, async-await, python-requests, formatting

The code i am using

```py
    async def main():
        with open("urls.txt", "r") as f:
            urls = f.read().splitlines()
    
        table = []  # Initialize table
        headers = ["URL", "Cat Username", "Potato Username", "IID", "Passwords"]
        url_color = Fore.RED
        Cat_username_color = Fore.GREEN
        Potato_username_color = Fore.YELLOW
        IID_color = Fore.BLUE
        password_color = Fore.MAGENTA  # add color for Passwords
    
        tasks = []
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            for url in urls:
                tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(get_IID_password(session, url)))
    
    # Print table headers
    print(f"{url_color}URL{Style.RESET_ALL} | {Cat_username_color}Cat-Username{Style.RESET_ALL} | {Potato_username_color}Potato-Username{Style.RESET_ALL} | {IID_color}IID{Style.RESET_ALL} | {password_color}Passwords{Style.RESET_ALL}")
    
            # Print table separator
            print("-" * 80)
    
            for task in asyncio.as_completed(tasks):
                try:
                    result = await task
                    if result and result not in table: # check if result is not already in table to avoid duplicates
                        table.append([url_color + result["URL"], Cat_username_color + result["Cat Username"], Potato_username_color + result["Potato Username"], IID_color + result["IID"], password_color + result["Passwords"] + Style.RESET_ALL])  # Use password_color for Passwords
                        # Print updated table
                        os.system('cls')
                        print(tabulate(table, headers=headers, tablefmt="fancy_grid"))
                        print("\033[F" * (len(table) + 1))
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"{Fore.RED}Error: {e}{Style.RESET_ALL}")
```

I added `os.system('cls')` as a workaround but it made things worse

target behavior is : print the new addition to the table only just like a drawing

what happens : the whole table gets reprinted with each result

an ugly fix i found on [stackoverflow using str.format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33678788/9889643)

```py
        template = '{:<25} | {:<25} | {:<25} | {:<25} | {:<25}' # numbers are width, '<' means 'align to left'
        print(template.format(*headers))
        print(template.replace(':', ':-').replace('<', '^').replace('|', '+').format('', '', '', '', ''))

        for task in asyncio.as_completed(tasks):
            try:
                result = await task
                if result and result not in table: # check if result is not already in table to avoid duplicates
                    table.append([result["URL"], result["Cat Username"], result["Potato Username"], result["IID"], result["Passwords"]]) 
                    # Print updated table
                    for row in table[len(table)-1:]:
                        print(template.format(url_color + row[0], cat_username_color + row[1], potato_username_color + row[2], iid_color + row[3], passwords_color + row[4] + Style.RESET_ALL))
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"{Fore.RED}Error: {e}{Style.RESET_ALL}")
```

is what i am asking even possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the fix , i worked more on the ugly code and now it looks good (to some level )

```py
async def main():
    with open("urls.txt", "r") as f:
        urls = f.read().splitlines()

    table = []  # Initialize table
    headers = ["#", "URL", "Cat Username", "Potato Username", "IID", "Passwords"]
    url_color = Fore.RED
    cat_username_color = Fore.GREEN
    potato_username_color = Fore.YELLOW
    iid_color = Fore.BLUE
    passwords_color = Fore.MAGENTA  # Add color for WIFI-Password

    tasks = []
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        for url in urls:
            tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(get_essid_password(session, url)))

        # Print table headers
        template = '{:<3} | {:<34} | {:<30} | {:<30} | {:<30} | {:<25}' # numbers are width, '<' means 'align to left'
        table_header = template.format("#", url_color + headers[1], cat_username_color + headers[2], potato_username_color + headers[3], iid_color + headers[4], passwords_color + headers[5] + Style.RESET_ALL)
        separator = Fore.CYAN + "-" * len(table_header) + Style.RESET_ALL
        print(separator)
        print(table_header + "|")
        print(separator)

        count = 0
        for task in asyncio.as_completed(tasks):
            try:
                result = await task
                if result and result not in table: # check if result is not already in table to avoid duplicates
                    count += 1
                    table.append([count, result["URL"], result["Cat Username"], result["Potato Username"], result["IID"], result["Passwords"]]) 
                    # Print updated table
                    for row in table[len(table)-1:]:
                        table_row = template.format(str(row[0]), url_color + row[1], cat_username_color + row[2], potato_username_color + row[3], iid_color + row[4], passwords_color + row[5] + Style.RESET_ALL)
                        separator = Fore.CYAN + "-" * len(table_row) + Style.RESET_ALL # Add separator with the same length as row
                        print(table_row + "|")
                        print(separator)

            except Exception as e:
                print(f"{Fore.RED}Error: {e}{Style.RESET_ALL}")

asyncio.run(main())
```

[image]